# Sending arguments to the Gtk create method

Tags: c++, c++11, gtk

I am trying to call Gtk::Application::create method that has the following signature.

```
create(int& argc, char**& argv, const Glib::ustring& application_id = Glib::ustring(), Gio::ApplicationFlags flags = Gio::APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
```

So in my C++11 code I wrote:

```
char *argv[] = {"arg1", "arg2", nullptr};
int argc = 2;
auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
```

But I am getting this error:

```
no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘char* [3]’ to ‘char**&’
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gtk::Application::create` modifies its arguments, so your `argv` needs to be a pointer lvalue:

```
char *args[] = {"arg1", "arg2", nullptr};
char** argv = args;
int argc = 2;
auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
```

An array is not a pointer lvalue; it decays to a pointer, but that pointer is a prvalue.

Note that the above is still incorrect, as it relies on being able to use a string literal as a `char*`. You should instead use a 3-step process:

```
std::string[] args = {"arg1", "arg2"};
char* argp[] = {&args[0][0], &args[1][0], nullptr};
char** argv = argp;
int argc = 2;
auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
```